# Rotate screen using udl driver (DisplayLink) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xorg, drivers, usb-drive

Recently got a `DisplayLink` device, it works, but I would like to rotate counter-clockwise. Apparently the driver does not allow rotation (tried via `gnome-shell` and `xrandr`).

Searching on google I found this [link](http://plugable.com/2010/01/02/displaylink-linux-rotation) but it seems a bit outdated. The configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not exist in my distribution, I guess `Xorg` uses another configuration structure.

Any tips on how I could rotate the screen in Ubuntu 14.04?

> Kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic
>   Xorg: 1.15.1
>   Device: Bus 002 Device 011: ID 17e9: 019e DisplayLink (DL-165?)

Comment: Today, you can just put the advised configuration in a new file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

Comment: I`m with the same problem. I have the monitor working following this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink but there is no way, as far as I know, to use xrandr to rotate the screen.

Comment: Same here, searching for a solution...

Comment: Maybe the latest (1.1.0.138, 15/12/2015) driver solves the issues? http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu